# Pre Process XML file to be used in unmarshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, xjc

I have a very very large xml file where each attribute occupies one line as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<roo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://distribution.company.net/DDF/GID/1">
 <GID>1</GID>
 <Status>CLOSED</Status>
 <Name>ABC Company</Name>
  ........
</roo>
<?xml version="1.0">
<roo .......>
...........
```

I want to modify it so that the entire roo attribute and its sub attributes occupy one line with the header changed as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<roo xmlns = "http://distribution.company.net/DDF/GID/1"> <GID>1</GID> <Status>CLOSED</Status> ...........
```

This XML file is created by some other process. I don't have any control over how it is created.

The file is very huge (~20GB) . so I cannot manually change it

Comment: What do you hope to gain by removing the newlines?

Comment: I want to send one line at a time to the unmarshaller which creates objects of type ROM

Comment: What you show is not a valid XML file because it has more than one root element.

Comment: I am so sorry.. we have a new <?xml ... > declaration before it too.. infact before evry root element ..

Comment: So use the occurrence of the XML header to separate the files.  If they're all in one file it's still not valid XML

Comment: How big would one of the individual XML documents be on their own?

Comment: Around 500 attributes.. and the whole XML document is around 20GB